# how to add new row for every new login key word in object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var displayArray = [], tempstateData={readyDuration:0,notReadyDuration:0};

  localArray = [
    {"state":"LOGIN","startTime":"10.25"},
    
    {"state":"READY","startTime":"10.26","endTime":"10.35","duration":"615"},
    
    {"state":"NOT_READY","startTime":"11:26","endTime":"10.35","duration":"874"},
    
    {"state":"READY","startTime":"10.26","endTime":"10.35","duration":"222"},
    
    {"state":"NOT_READY","startTime":"11:26","endTime":"10.35","duration":"111"},
    
    {"state":"READY","startTime":"10.26","endTime":"10.35","duration":"333"},
    
    {"state":"NOT_READY","startTime":"11:26","endTime":"10.35","duration":"888"},
    
    {"state":"READY","startTime":"10.26","endTime":"10.35","duration":"444"},
    
    {"state":"NOT_READY","startTime":"11:26","endTime":"10.35","duration":"999"},
    
    {"state":"LOGOUT","startTime":"13.26"},
    // he logged in again, so we need to add new row
    {"state":"LOGIN","startTime":"08.58"},
    
    {"state":"READY","startTime":"10.26","endTime":"10.35","duration":"12"},
    
    {"state":"NOT_READY","startTime":"11:26","endTime":"10.35","duration":"13"},
    
    {"state":"READY","startTime":"10.26","endTime":"10.35","duration":"14"},
    
    {"state":"NOT_READY","startTime":"11:26","endTime":"10.35","duration":"15"},
    
    {"state":"READY","startTime":"10.26","endTime":"10.35","duration":"16"},
    
    {"state":"NOT_READY","startTime":"11:26","endTime":"10.35","duration":"17"},
    
    {"state":"READY","startTime":"10.26","endTime":"10.35","duration":"18"},
    
    {"state":"NOT_READY","startTime":"11:26","endTime":"10.35","duration":"19"}
    ];
    //alert(JSON.stringify(localArray));
    for(i=0;i<localArray.length;i++){
    tempOBJ = localArray[i];
    if(tempOBJ.state == "LOGIN")
    {
        tempstateData.loginTime = tempOBJ.startTime;
    }
    if(tempOBJ.state == "READY")
    {
  tempstateData.readyDuration = tempstateData.readyDuration + parseInt(tempOBJ.duration);
    }
    if(tempOBJ.state == "NOT_READY")
    {
        tempstateData.notReadyDuration = tempstateData.notReadyDuration + parseInt(tempOBJ.duration);
    }
    if(tempOBJ.state == "LOGOUT")
    {
        tempstateData.logOutTime = tempOBJ.startTime;
    }
    displayArray.push(tempstateData);
   //alert(JSON.stringify(tempstateData));
    row = "<tr><td>"+displayArray[i].loginTime+"</td><td>"+displayArray[i].readyDuration+"</td><td>"+displayArray[i].notReadyDuration+"</td><td>"+displayArray[i].logOutTime+"</td></tr>";
    }
    
    $('#dataAdd').append(row);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
<thead>
<th>Login Time</th>
<th>Ready Duration</th>
<th>Not_ready Duration</th>
<th>Logout Time</th>
</thead>
<tbody id="dataAdd"></tbody>
<table>

</body>
</html>
```

Here i have some array of object which contains two LOGINs(may have more than two logins in future) in object. For every login i need to add all READY durations and NOT_READY Durations and have to show it in one row irrespective of STATE:LOGOUT

i did for first login and i am getting any idea how to get new row for new login(Which Dont have STATE:LOGOUT yet)?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esentially what you want to do is aggregate up all of your data, forming an array of login events with the relevant info within. This can be done with `reduce`

```
const result = localArray.reduce( (acc,i) => {
   if(i.state == "LOGIN"){
      acc.push({loginTime:i.startTime,readyDuration:0,notReadyDuration:0,logOutTime:null });
   }
   if(i.state == "READY"){
      acc[acc.length-1].readyDuration += parseInt(i.duration,10);
   }
   if(i.state == "NOT_READY"){
      acc[acc.length-1].notReadyDuration += parseInt(i.duration,10);
   }
   if(i.state == "LOGOUT"){
      acc[acc.length-1].logOutTime = i.startTime;
   }
   return acc;
},[]);
```

This will produce an array, which you can then loop over to build your rows - demonstration below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  localArray = [
    {"state":"LOGIN","startTime":"10.25"},
    
    {"state":"READY","startTime":"10.26","endTime":"10.35","duration":"615"},
    
    {"state":"NOT_READY","startTime":"11:26","endTime":"10.35","duration":"874"},
    
    {"state":"READY","startTime":"10.26","endTime":"10.35","duration":"222"},
    
    {"state":"NOT_READY","startTime":"11:26","endTime":"10.35","duration":"111"},
    
    {"state":"READY","startTime":"10.26","endTime":"10.35","duration":"333"},
    
    {"state":"NOT_READY","startTime":"11:26","endTime":"10.35","duration":"888"},
    
    {"state":"READY","startTime":"10.26","endTime":"10.35","duration":"444"},
    
    {"state":"NOT_READY","startTime":"11:26","endTime":"10.35","duration":"999"},
    
    {"state":"LOGOUT","startTime":"13.26"},
    // he logged in again, so we need to add new row
    {"state":"LOGIN","startTime":"08.58"},
    
    {"state":"READY","startTime":"10.26","endTime":"10.35","duration":"12"},
    
    {"state":"NOT_READY","startTime":"11:26","endTime":"10.35","duration":"13"},
    
    {"state":"READY","startTime":"10.26","endTime":"10.35","duration":"14"},
    
    {"state":"NOT_READY","startTime":"11:26","endTime":"10.35","duration":"15"},
    
    {"state":"READY","startTime":"10.26","endTime":"10.35","duration":"16"},
    
    {"state":"NOT_READY","startTime":"11:26","endTime":"10.35","duration":"17"},
    
    {"state":"READY","startTime":"10.26","endTime":"10.35","duration":"18"},
    
    {"state":"NOT_READY","startTime":"11:26","endTime":"10.35","duration":"19"}
    ];
    const result = localArray.reduce( (acc,i) => {
       if(i.state == "LOGIN"){
          acc.push({loginTime:i.startTime,readyDuration:0,notReadyDuration:0,logOutTime:null });
       }
       if(i.state == "READY"){
          acc[acc.length-1].readyDuration += parseInt(i.duration,10);
       }
       if(i.state == "NOT_READY"){
          acc[acc.length-1].notReadyDuration += parseInt(i.duration,10);
       }
       if(i.state == "LOGOUT"){
          acc[acc.length-1].logOutTime = i.startTime;
       }
       return acc;
    },[]);
    
    for(let i=0;i<result.length;i++){
      const row = "<tr><td>"+result[i].loginTime+"</td><td>"+result[i].readyDuration+"</td><td>"+result[i].notReadyDuration+"</td><td>"+result[i].logOutTime+"</td></tr>";
      

      $('#dataAdd').append(row);
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
<thead>
<th>Login Time</th>
<th>Ready Duration</th>
<th>Not_ready Duration</th>
<th>Logout Time</th>
</thead>
<tbody id="dataAdd"></tbody>
<table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "state machine" to accumulate the data and reset it as you go.

Update: Support for case when didn't logout last.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  localArray = [{
      "state": "LOGIN",
      "startTime": "10.25"
    },

    {
      "state": "READY",
      "startTime": "10.26",
      "endTime": "10.35",
      "duration": "615"
    },

    {
      "state": "NOT_READY",
      "startTime": "11:26",
      "endTime": "10.35",
      "duration": "874"
    },

    {
      "state": "READY",
      "startTime": "10.26",
      "endTime": "10.35",
      "duration": "222"
    },

    {
      "state": "NOT_READY",
      "startTime": "11:26",
      "endTime": "10.35",
      "duration": "111"
    },

    {
      "state": "READY",
      "startTime": "10.26",
      "endTime": "10.35",
      "duration": "333"
    },

    {
      "state": "NOT_READY",
      "startTime": "11:26",
      "endTime": "10.35",
      "duration": "888"
    },

    {
      "state": "READY",
      "startTime": "10.26",
      "endTime": "10.35",
      "duration": "444"
    },

    {
      "state": "NOT_READY",
      "startTime": "11:26",
      "endTime": "10.35",
      "duration": "999"
    },

    {
      "state": "LOGOUT",
      "startTime": "13.26"
    },
    {
      "state": "LOGIN",
      "startTime": "08.58"
    },

    {
      "state": "READY",
      "startTime": "10.26",
      "endTime": "10.35",
      "duration": "12"
    },

    {
      "state": "NOT_READY",
      "startTime": "11:26",
      "endTime": "10.35",
      "duration": "13"
    },

    {
      "state": "READY",
      "startTime": "10.26",
      "endTime": "10.35",
      "duration": "14"
    },

    {
      "state": "NOT_READY",
      "startTime": "11:26",
      "endTime": "10.35",
      "duration": "15"
    },

    {
      "state": "READY",
      "startTime": "10.26",
      "endTime": "10.35",
      "duration": "16"
    },

    {
      "state": "NOT_READY",
      "startTime": "11:26",
      "endTime": "10.35",
      "duration": "17"
    },

    {
      "state": "READY",
      "startTime": "10.26",
      "endTime": "10.35",
      "duration": "18"
    },

    {
      "state": "NOT_READY",
      "startTime": "11:26",
      "endTime": "10.35",
      "duration": "19"
    },

    {
      "state": "LOGOUT",
      "startTime": "09.45"
    },

    {
      "state": "LOGIN",
      "startTime": "09:58"
    },

    {
      "state": "READY",
      "startTime": "10.26",
      "endTime": "10.35",
      "duration": "12"
    },

    {
      "state": "NOT_READY",
      "startTime": "11:26",
      "endTime": "10.35",
      "duration": "13"
    },

    {
      "state": "READY",
      "startTime": "10.26",
      "endTime": "10.35",
      "duration": "14"
    },

    {
      "state": "NOT_READY",
      "startTime": "11:26",
      "endTime": "10.35",
      "duration": "15"
    }
  ];

  var state = null;
  var bucket = null;

  for (i = 0; i < localArray.length; i++) {
    tempOBJ = localArray[i];

    if (tempOBJ.state == "LOGIN") {
      state = "STATE_LOGIN";
      bucket = {
        login: tempOBJ.startTime,
        ready: 0,
        not_ready: 0,
      };
      continue;
    }

    if (state == "STATE_LOGIN") {

      if (tempOBJ.state == "READY") {
        bucket.ready += parseInt(tempOBJ.duration, 10);
      }
      if (tempOBJ.state == "NOT_READY") {
        bucket.not_ready += parseInt(tempOBJ.duration, 10);
      }
      if (tempOBJ.state == "LOGOUT") {
        row = "<tr><td>" + bucket.login + "</td><td>" + bucket.ready + "</td><td>" + bucket.not_ready + "</td><td>" + tempOBJ.startTime + "</td></tr>";
        $('#dataAdd').append(row);
        state = null;
      }

    }

  }

  if (state != null) {
    row = "<tr><td>" + bucket.login + "</td><td>" + bucket.ready + "</td><td>" + bucket.not_ready + "</td><td>" + "..." + "</td></tr>";
    $('#dataAdd').append(row);
    state = null;
  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <th>Login Time</th>
    <th>Ready Duration</th>
    <th>Not_ready Duration</th>
    <th>Logout Time</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="dataAdd"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: it works fine until we have State:LOGOUT in the object but still i have to add READY DURATION AND NOT_READY durations even if he dint logged out

Comment: Do you mean for the last row of the table?

Comment: yeah, consider in the last we dontt have STATE:LOGOUT object, still i have to add ready and not ready durations

Comment: which means user logged in for the first time, he has done some ready and not ready opearions and logged out again after some time he logged in and made some changes in ready n not ready states, but here he dint logged out. so i have to add ready n not ready durations for both rows in the table.

Comment: i have updated my Object in my question